# Какие средства использовать для вывода данных в режиме реального времени с частотой 240Гц в оконном приложении?

Tags: desktop, realtime

Есть задача в виде написания оконного приложения, читающего данные с COM-порта, выводящего их на график и считающего интеграл. Какой язык и среду программирования (графическую библиотеку и т.п.) стоит выбрать для этой задачи?

Данные поступают со скоростью 19200 бод, за одну секунду 220-240 точек данных. Была попытка реализовать это на C#+WindowsForms, но стандартный компонент TChart с задачей не справлялся и зависал, поэтому приходилось ставить на график только 40 точек в секунду. Для задачи это +- приемлемо, но хотелось бы лучше, чтобы была возможность видеть незначительные флуктуации входных значений.

Можно ли достичь с помощью чего-либо большей производительности?

Comment: вопрос очень общий, я уверен и ваш график бы справился, просто вы наверняка кормите ему все данные целиком, а нужно только "актуальный участок" исходя из того сколько точек можно одновременно рассмотреть на экране. а остальное в памяти держать, но это уже совсем другая история

Comment: Так и делали на самом деле. Брали период 3с.

Comment: 100 тысяч точек https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/QojQyJ

Comment: это библиотека plotly.js, весь код, который необходим чтобы это с ней нарисовать вы можете наблюдать по ссылке

Comment: Спасибо! Я правильно понимаю, что мне тогда нужно будет писать приложение полностью на JS и запускать его в браузере? Там еще БД нужна для этой задачи. Как это все вместе можно будет собрать?

Comment: можно браузер встроить в приложение,и написать логику на чем вам удобно, а в браузере только нарисовать =)

Comment: Ух ты, интересно! А есть примеры какие-нибудь? Пусть не то же самое, но хотя бы подобное.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_Embedded_Framework

Comment: Видимо, что-то делалось неправильно, поскольку 240x3=720 точек с постоянным обновлением ("режим осциллографа") на графике должно отображаться нормально. По крайней мере, в Delphi TChart в таком режиме несколько тысяч точек отображает, проблемы начинаются при выводе более десяти тысяч  (потому что перерасчёт пределов сделан внутри неоптимально). 240 раз в секунду обновлять явно не стоит, ни монитор это не покажет, ни человек не заметит.